# How can I promote my work?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling

After a half year of working as a data scientist, I found myself tend to clone my previous work (in machine learning, like predictive modeling, EDA, data preprocessing etc.) in the new project and the work becomes a repeated style.

I need new directions to lift my work with some innovative pieces. That is a key incentive to my work and also make me feel fresh and confident.

Could anyone put forth advice for me? Cheers

Comment: I don't completly understand your question, but it seems like http://academia.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: Study Deep learning --> do some project --> post it on github/make an app/make a webiste.